# How to generate a test Signing Certificate to set up an Authorization Server (Identity Server 3)?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, oauth-2.0, jwt, identityserver3

I am setting up an Authorization Server using Identity Server 3, AOuth and ASP.NET following a tutorial, but I am stuck as I haven't been able to generate a hardcoded test Signing Certificate to set it on app settings on the Web.Config.

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="SigningCertificate" value="HARDCODED SIGNING CERTIFICATE"/>
     <add key="SigningCertificatePassword" value="password"/>
</appSettings>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

I am trying to use this Signing Certificate on the Startup class on the Configuration method.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var inMemoryManager = new InMemoryManager();

        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
            .UseInMemoryUsers(inMemoryManager.GetUsers()) // THIS IS TO USE IN MEMORY USERS. FOR NOW
            .UseInMemoryScopes(inMemoryManager.GetScopes())
            .UseInMemoryClients(inMemoryManager.GetClients());

            var certificate = Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningCertificate"]);
            // var certificate = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\TestCert\certificate.pfx"));

        var options = new IdentityServerOptions
        {  
            SigningCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningCertificatePassword"]),
            RequireSsl = false, // DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION. JUST TO RUN IT HERE LOCALLY
            Factory = factory
        };

        app.UseIdentityServer(options);
    }
```

I am not very familiar with this area of ASP.NET. Does anybody know how I can get mu Authorization Server working?

Edit: Command not generating certificate.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03JSv.jpg)

Comment: Here's how to get makecert to gen you a signing cert: https://brockallen.com/2015/06/01/makecert-and-creating-ssl-or-signing-certificates/

Comment: Thanks @BrockAllen. I run the script on Developer Command Promt for VS2015 successfully; however, I couldn't find the certificate on C:Windows\System32. What is the name of the file that is generated? and, Is it created somewhere else by default?

Comment: @Banana the cert will appear in your current working directory within powershell/command prompt.

Comment: It isn't. I moved the working directory to : C:\TestCert, executed the command again and still nothing... The TestCert directory is empty. I even tried showing hidden files

Comment: It's added to the certificate store -- run mmc and load in the user's cert store snapin